# Where can I find Android Design Guidelines for specific version (KitKat, Gingerbread, etc)?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, design-guidelines, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I've been looking around and couldn't find an archive for previous versions of Android where you can checkout how GUI was done back then.

I'm developing an application and want to make its UI consistent with the platform version it's running into.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use the Material design for all versions.

Comment: I agree there's a need to access older design specs. We do not all have budget to instantly rewrite or update all previous implementations. So in the meantime, you have to make decisions maintaining your app's current look-and-feel. But the Material guidelines have overwritten all older design specifications, with no apparent links to the previous editions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do correct me if I'm mistaken but prior to Material Design (API 21+) there wasn't any thoroughly documented and specified guidelines for Android apps.

Your best bet is to use some sort of internet archive browser services, such as [The Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), and explore Android's own design page - `d.android.com/design`.

As a starting point, [here's said page captured on January 1st, 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101160706/http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). You could still see informations about Holo there. I imagine you could go even further to the past to find more.